# Strategy for optimizing speed of humungous search

Tags: python, performance, optimization

Overview: I want to find out which of 50,000 "words" from 3-15 characters long are present at least once in a database of 100 million "sentences" from 50 to 1200 characters long without spaces but with line breaks.

(Why? It's a proteomics project. The "words" are peptide sequences, e.g. MRQNTWAAV, and the sentences are complete protein sequences, e.g. MRQNTWAAVTGGQTNRALI... There are proteomics tools to do searches, but they would be even less efficient, because they are afaik optimized for long query strings and for non-exact matches.)

Also, I'll be doing this on a regular PC, 8 GB RAM.

I'm new to python, being a scientist by trade, not a programmer; I wrote a script but it's quite slow (in my opinion). Since I only want to find out which terms are present at least once, I thought I'd speed things up by:

- splitting up the reference database into 200 parts of 500,000 sentences
- iterating over these partial databases, loading each one into memory with mmain
- loading the list of query terms into a list in memory
- iterating over the list using mmain's find (not regex, of course!), and writing the terms that are NOT found into a new list of query terms
- when the loop goes to the next database, making a new list of the shorter file of query terms
- etc.

Here is my code: as I said I'm not a programmer, so I know it's not optimal. It certainly works fine with a pared down sample set. If there are some fundamental design features that might help it run faster (I don't care if it takes overnight, but I'm hoping it won't take days ... I admit I haven't systematically timed it yet.)

A couple of things that immediately occur to me:
- Would database files larger or smaller than 50 MB be more optimal?
- I'm sure I should I keep the list of "not found" terms in memory, only writing it to disk at the end of the process. I did it this way so I could gauge the process during this design stage.

```
import os
import mmap
import glob

os.chdir("C:/mysearch/")
searchtermfile = "original_search_terms.txt"

# load list of 50,000 search terms into memory as a list
with open(searchtermfile, 'r') as f:
    searchtermlist = [line.strip() for line in f]
    numberofsearchterms = len(searchtermlist)


#make a list of database files in the directory
dblist = glob.glob('databasepart*.txt') 
sizedblist = len(dblist)

counterdb = 0 #counts the iterations over the database files
countersearchterms = 0 #counts the iterations over the search terms
previousstring = "DUMMY" #a dummy value just for the first time it's used

#iterate first over list of file names
for nameoffile in dblist:
    counterdb += 1
    countersearchterms = 0
    #remove old notfound list, this iteration will make a new, shorter one.
    os.remove("notfound.txt") #returns an error if there is not already a notfound.txt file; I always make sure there's an empty file with that name
    #read current database file (50 MB) into memory
    with open(nameoffile, 'r+b') as f:
        m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0) #Size 0 reads entire file into memory
        #iterate over search terms
        for searchstring in searchtermlist:
            countersearchterms += 1
            if m.find(searchstring) == -1:
                with open("notfound.txt", "a") as myfile:
                    myfile.write(searchstring + "\n")
            #this print line won't be there in the final code, it's allowing me to see how fast this program runs
            print str(counterdb) + " of " + str(sizedblist) + " & " + str(countersearchterms) + " of " + str(numberofsearchterms)
            previousstring = searchstring
        m.close()
    #reload saved list of not found terms as new search term list
    with open('notfound.txt', 'r') as f:
        searchtermlist = [line.strip() for line in f]
        numberofsearchterms = len(searchtermlist)
```

Comment: Because you stated your code works, I've corrected your indentation where it was obviously wrong; do verify that your code, as displayed here, is now correctly reflecting what you are actually working with.

Comment: I'd try the existing tools first. They might be better optimized for your use case than you think.

Comment: You say you're "of course" not using regexes, but actually I'd go that way. Compiled regex are supposed to be rather efficient automatons for string searching. Do you need that the sequences may overlap? If not you can go the findall way which has the advantage to be a hard coded loop.

Comment: I think the greatest speed gains here can be had from changing the algorithm into something that isn't O(Nword*Nseq). How about something like this: Choose a chunk length M. Create a hash map mapping from chunk value to the parent sequence. Then repeat this with the start of each chunk offset by 1, 2, .., M-1. This will take O(Nseq*M). To search for a given word, look up its first M characters in the hash map. This will give you a list of matching sequences to look for, which will hopefully be much shorter than the full set. The total performance will be something like O(Nseq*M + Nword).

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank you, something weird happened to my indents somewhere while copy pasting my mixture of tabs and spaces (oops).

Comment: @Cilyan, my "of course" was not a well chosen phrase, I just read a couple of times in upvoted StackOverflow comments that one should use a regular find instead of regex for exact searches unless you're using the same search term over and over; perhaps I misunderstood. I am using the same list of terms over and over, is that equivalent? Could I compile 50,000 terms?

Comment: @amaurea, that sounds great, I see the logic, I just need to figure out what a hash map is and how to make one; it sounds like a python dict.

Comment: @user2357112, you may well be right. I tried BLAST first with an identity matrix and a large gap penalty and it was really slow, but I don't think it was slower than this.

Comment: @prooffreader: Yes, python dicts are implemented using hash tables. So you would have dictionaries of {str: [list of sequences]}. To be honest, though, this is the sort of problem where I would implement the core in another language for speed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could however try using regexes:

```py
>>> searchterms = ["A", "B", "AB", "ABC", "C", "BC"]
>>> # To match longest sequences first, yes need to place them at the beginning
>>> searchterms.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
>>> searchterms
['ABC', 'AB', 'BC', 'A', 'B', 'C']
>>> # Compile a big regex searching all terms together
>>> _regex =re.compile("("+"|".join(searchterms)+")")
>>> _regex.findall("ABCBADCBDACBDACBDCBADCBADBCBCBDACBDACBDACBDABCDABC")
['ABC', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'BC', 'BC', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'ABC', 'ABC']
>>>
```

You may use `finditer` instead if you are only interested in counting the matches.

Comment: Wow. A compiled regex with 50,000 terms! It hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: Well, you want the computer to do the work, anyway? And you will have somehow to iterate over all the characters of all terms for all the strings you check against. :) This method is used in DokuWiki (there are fewer parts, but the regexes are more complex).

Comment: I tried to create such a regex on a regular PC with a test set of 50,000 elements 3 to 15 characters long and it took 2.35 seconds.

Comment: I tested it on a 10MB string and it took 26 minutes to match all overlapping occurrences. I don't known how your own code performed in comparison. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8438901

Answer (score 0):

I have less experience with python, so personally I would do it in C or C++.
The problem is simplified because you are only looking for exact matches.

The inner loop is where all the time is spent, so I would concentrate on that.

First, I would take the list of 5e4 terms, sort them, put them in a table for binary search, or (better yet) put them in a trie structure for letter-by-letter search.

Then, at each character position in the "sentence", call the search function.
It should be pretty fast.
In principle, a hash table would have O(1) performance, but the constant factor is important.
I would bet money the trie still beats it in this case, and you can tune the daylights out of it.